# ios: how to imitate Android viewflipper control / multiview tree of decision?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I need to implement a tree of decisions, very simple, not complicated in objective c for iphone / ipad, just a few questions with yes or no and I show some other questions depending on decisions, and finally the app got out of these questions and we get to the core of the app.

In Android I used a viewflipper control, which is like the .NET multiview control, in the sense that in a same control / view you move from one option to the other, it is very simple, you don't have to create as many viewcontrollers as questions / decisions to take.

So, down to the facts:
- best way to create a screen where user gives us info based on questions. My first idea from other programming languages it's a multiview control.
- One solution could be to make disappear different views in a viewcontroller, in that case, please some advices to make it with any interesting animation (with viewflipper you create whatever animation you like).

Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution has been the following:

- I have added the views I needed in the Interface Builder, I have put them one besides the other, no need to stack one on top of the other, it's easier to modify.
- When I need to show one view I assign the "self.view" to the view I need:

> ```
> view1.hidden=YES; 
> self.view=view2;
> view2.hidden=NO;
> ```

If you want to make any transition, we have to include the QuartzCore Framework in the libraries, and then you can use CATransition:

> ```
> CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
> transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
> transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight;
> [self.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:@"push-transition"];
> ```